# How to define the maven dependency, if jar is already included in project

Tags: maven

Maven dependency created as below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group_id</groupId>
  <artifactId>artificat_id</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The related jar is stored under the path `project_folder_test/modules/api/repo/com/common/2.5.0`

After running the command `mvn clean compile`, getting the below error

```
Downloading: file:///Users/Automation/project_folder_test/modules/api/repo/com/common/2.5.0/common-2.5.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/common/2.5.0/common-2.5.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for group_id:artificat_id:jar:2.5.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

please let me know, what went wrong in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add local jar files in maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy you jar to a location file system :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///path/to/yourproject/repo/ -Dfile=mylib-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=mylib -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0
```

Add a repository section to your pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your reply